# Set height 0 px after another transition ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    .aa{
        width:300px;
        height:auto;
        background : red;
        transition : width 1s ease;
    }
    .bb {
        width:100px;
        height:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
<body>


<div class="aa">Lorem Ipsum, dizgi ve baskı endüstrisinde kullanılan mıgır metinlerdir. Lorem Ipsum, adı bilinmeyen bir matbaacının bir hurufat numune kitabı oluşturmak üzere bir yazı galerisini alarak karıştırdığı.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the codepen link:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBmeNK

When I add ".bb" class to the my div element:
First I want my width transition to be happened and after width transition I want to my div to have 0px height and overflow hidden.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please add javascript part to your codepen.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another class with just `height: 0` and `overflow: hidden` after `transitionend` event is fired on the taget element (your div) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

Answer (score 0):

You can define a transition using keyframes. There are plenty of guides:"

[CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

```
@keyframes my-transition {
  0%   { height: 100px; }
  100% { height: 0; overflow: hidden }
}
```

And then you can add it to you css:

```
.my-animated-class { 
   transition: my-transition 1s ease-out
}
```

EDIT: To make it clear, there are a few things off about your codepen:

- You are not importing jQuery
- You are not using jQuery
- You are not sharing how you intend to add the class.

Comment: Can you explain more?How can this be the solution to the my problem?

Comment: Well you need to add jQuery code to actually apply the class